# Does Parallel.ForEach Block?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, logging, parallel-processing

Does the .net function [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx) block the calling thread? My guess as to the behavior is one of these:

1. Yes, it blocks until the slowest item executing returns.
2. No, it doesn't block and returns control immediately. The items to run in parallel are done on background threads.

Or perhaps something else is happening, anyone know for sure?

This question came up when implementing this in a logging class:

```
public class MultipleLoggingService : LoggingServiceBase
{
    private readonly List<LoggingServiceBase> loggingServices;

    public MultipleLoggingService(List<LoggingServiceBase> loggingServices)
    {
        this.loggingServices = loggingServices;
        LogLevelChanged += OnLogLevelChanged;
    }

    private void OnLogLevelChanged(object sender, LogLevelChangedArgs args)
    {
        loggingServices.ForEach(l => l.LogLevel = LogLevel);
    }

    public override LogMessageResponse LogMessage(LogMessageRequest request)
    {
        if (request.LogMessage)
            Parallel.ForEach(loggingServices, l => l.LogMessage(request));

        return new LogMessageResponse{MessageLogged = request.LogMessage};
    }
}
```

Notice the `LogMessage` method calls some other logging services. I need that part to return immediately, so it doesn't block the calling thread.

---

Update: Based on comments from others (we have confirmed the behavior is #1). So I have taken advice to use the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) library and rewritten the loop like this:

```
          if (request.LogMessage)
            foreach (var loggingService in loggingServices)
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => loggingService.LogMessage(request));
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Number 1 is correct; `Parallel.ForEach` does not return until the loop has completed. If you don't want that behavior, you can simply execute your loop as a `Task` and run it on another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Do you happen to have a little code snippet on how to use 'Task' in this context? Thanks, Paul

Comment: @PaulFryer: `Task t = Task.TaskFactory.StartNew(() => {/* Parallel.For goes here */});`

Comment: Technically, the calling thread is used in the parallel loop. So it's not "wasted" just blocking on the loop - it's used as one of the worker threads.

Answer (score 12):

Re your update, StartNew in a normal foreach() :

This may not be the most optimal for large collections, and you don't get a point to handle errors.

Your loggingServices probably doesn't hold thousands of items but the errorhandling remains a point .

Consider:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
   try
   {
        Parallel.ForEach(loggingServices, l => l.LogMessage(request));
   }
   catch(SomeException ex)
   {
       // at least try to log it ...
   }
});
```

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll have to think about this one for a bit, if the logging service fails, how to log the error :-)