# How to unblock "primary" thread for UI in winforms (using Parallel.Foreach)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, parallel.foreach

using c#, .Net Framework 4.5, VS 2012

Try to use `Parallel.Foreach`

As result has some UI and add method for button (method allow to rotate all pic in folder and save in another place)

```
private void ProcessFileParallel()
    {
        string[] files =
            Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures",
            "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories); //get source folder
        string dirNew = @"C:\modifiedImages"; //new folder
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirNew); //create dir
        //usage of parallel and lambda
        Parallel.ForEach(files, currfiles =>
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(currfiles); //get cur name of file
             //GC for Bitmap
             //create new object of Bitmap
             using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(currfiles))
            {
                bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX); //rotating
                bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(dirNew, fileName)); //save as
                 //anonym delegate - used for safety access to UI elements from secondary thread
                this.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    //caption name change for form
                    this.Text = 
                        string.Format("Curr Thread {0}", 
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }
                );
            }
        }
        );            
    }
```

it's work, but after end (when all pic rotated and saved in new place, and UI got at top something like `Curr Thread 11`) primary thread is locked - means UI not active - can't do anything. 
Question - How can i unlock my UI elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out writing a comment, but it quickly became too long.

First off, I agree that ChrisK's answer is, indeed, a good solution to the problem. As an academic exercise, however, I think it's worth explaining *why* the issue happens in the first place.

`Parallel.ForEach` blocks the thread it's called on (which is the UI thread in your case) until all parallel operations have completed. At the same time you've got other threads trying to synchronously invoke actions on the UI thread (which is already blocked). Those invokes have to wait for the UI thread to unblock, but it won't unblock until all non-UI threads have finished their work (which they can't, because they're waiting). Checkmate. You have a deadlock, and your call to `Parallel.ForEach` will never complete.

Realistically you could have solved your issue by simply substituting `this.Invoke` with `this.BeginInvoke`, which posts work to the UI thread asynchronously and thus allows non-UI threads to keep going and eventually complete; however I do maintain that offloading the actual call to `Parallel.ForEach` to the thread pool via a `Task` (as suggested by ChrisK) is a better solution all around.

P.S. On an unrelated note, your call to `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` is always invoked on the UI thread, and therefore will always return *the ID of your UI thread*, which may or may not be the thread doing the work on the image. If you want to know which actual thread is doing the work you would have to store the return value from `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` outside of your delegate definition, and then close over it.

Comment: -You have a deadlock. - yep!!! Thanks for clear explanation! because just use `Task` instead  - not full answer that really can help

Comment: Just a side mark: In my opinion IO operations are not able to work parallely. Because the mechanical discs can only read at one address a time. 
I would first read every file after file, maybe a range of files. Then do the flips on the "in RAM saved files" in threads. After that, close file after file.

Comment: but as i understand parallel threading - not the parallel work - just a dummie - in real if you PC has 1 process - no parallel threading can be created - just fast switching between process - this create illusion of fast work for users, but if you have 2 or more processor - parallel thread have real sens

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski, agreed: when it comes to IO parallelisation can be a bit of a slippery slope. Personally this is where I'd be looking at pipelines to parallelise bits of work that are well-suited for it and keep the IO nice and sequential.

Comment: I did a test case. I have 1000 files with the same content created per code. Then i have used Parallel.ForEach and a normal sequential foreach to iterate through the filenames, creating a stream and append "Hello.".
With the StopWatch Class i have checked the ticks it took.
Firstly i've done in with Parallel.ForEach, that took avg. 4880 ticks. With a sequential foreach it took avg. 2480 ticks. I think this behaivour is because the thread is blocking while the IO device is actually reading, writing, opening or closing. So, better use sequential IO :-)

Comment: @Kirill, not all operations are a good fit for parallelisation. When dealing with resources which require sequential access (as is the case with a lot of IO resources - as pointed out by Dennis) the increased resource contention brought about by parallel access may lead to performance degradation. Parallelisation is a difficult but hugely interesting topic and if you wish to really dig into it, there's a free book I always recommend that addresses a lot of these caveats: *Patterns of Parallel Programming* (http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=19222)

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski, that's a nice benchmark, +1. If you have time you could look at writing up a parallelised solution which takes the IO bottleneck into account. Personally I'd be using TPL Dataflow or even a `BlockingCollection`-based pipeline with three stages - IO (sequential), processing (parallel), IO (sequential) - possibly, but not necessarily, with shared locking between stages 1 and 3 (if shown as beneficial by performance benchmarking). I'd be the first to upvote that as I really think people should be using good parallel programming patterns more.

Comment: @Kirill Shlenskiy thanks for a link to book - i just a beginners in programming -looks like as more I read, as more I understand that know nothing =)

Comment: Really interesting. I'm working on a solution that will fit! :-)

Comment: My research has the following result: The fastest is to make a normal foreach that will open, manipulate and close a file after and after. 
The three-step method (First open a range of files, manipulate it parallely, close them) will take too much communication between allocating and deallocating things.

Answer (score 3):

`Parallel.ForEach` blocks the thread until all loops are complete. If you want your UI to stay responsive you need to run it for instance in a Task. Also see this question, which is basically the same:

[Does Parallel.ForEach Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153729/does-parallel-foreach-block)