# Don't let GUI freeze with parallel.for due to the reading of a big array

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I'm trying to get a big string text array from a TextBox where lines are `string[]`.

It works but the problem is that with big amounts of data in input the GUI of program is frozen for a moment while it processes the entire size of the array (differently from async functions which don't let GUI to lag). To avoid the freeze? I'm trying to use parallel for but the result seems the same... How can I fix this?

```
string[] text = textBox.Lines;

if (textBox.Lines.Length > 0)
{
    Parallel.For(0, textBox.Lines.Length, x =>
    {
        text[x] = textBox.Lines[x];
    });
}
```

FIXED:

```
string[] text = textBox.Lines;

if (text.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Insert lines", "Error");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing all of that code with `string text[] = textBox.Lines;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Parallel.ForEach Block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153729/does-parallel-foreach-block)

Comment: Omg you're right, it's not necessary that loop.... Thanks all for helping me

Comment: It's really very very unlikely that you have enough lines in `textBox.Lines` to make using `Parallel.For` worthwhile anyway. There's a lot of overhead to creating/using threads. You need very CPU intensive code to make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `TextBox.Lines` property in your loop. You don't need to do this at all as the Lines property recreates a new string array each time it's accessed. Just get the Lines property, and you're done. You don't need to copy it line-by-line on the UI thread.

```
 string[] text = textBox.Lines; //Done.
```

To validate that it works as I describe, look at the source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/TextBoxBase.cs,37cabfde1449b18f,references