# Code seems to move on prior to Parallel.For loops finishing

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I'm struggling with using `Parallel.For` loops. I can tell they really speed up my long running code but I'm get null object errors as though the code moved on prior to completing the parallel loops. Below is my code with commented out `Parallel.For` statements that I've tried.

```
public bool Calculate()
{
    // make list of all possible flops 22100
    List<Flop> flops = new List<Flop>();
    CardSet deck = new CardSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.Size() - 2; i++)
    {
        SbCard card1 = deck.GetCard(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < deck.Size() - 1; j++)
        {
            SbCard card2 = deck.GetCard(j);
            for (int k = j + 1; k < deck.Size(); k++)
            {
                SbCard card3 = deck.GetCard(k);
                flops.Add(new Flop(card1, card2, card3));
            }
        }
    }

    int progress = 0;
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // Loop over each flop
    //Parallel.For(0, flops.Count, i =>
    for (int i = 0; i < flops.Count; i++)
    {
        Dictionary<FlopEquityHoldemHandPair, FlopEquityHoldemHandPair> flopPairs =
        new Dictionary<FlopEquityHoldemHandPair, FlopEquityHoldemHandPair>();
        Flop flop = flops[i];
        String filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\flops\\" +
        flop.GetSorted() + ".txt";

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // make list of all available starting hands
            List<HoldemHand> hands = new List<HoldemHand>();
            deck = new CardSet();
            deck.RemoveAll(flop);
            for (int j = 0; j < deck.Size() - 1; j++)
            {
                SbCard card1 = deck.GetCard(j);
                for (int k = j + 1; k < deck.Size(); k++)
                {
                    SbCard card2 = deck.GetCard(k);
                    hands.Add(new HoldemHand(card1, card2));
                }
            }

            // loop over all hand vs hand combos
            //Parallel.For(0, hands.Count - 1, j =>
            for (int j = 0; j < hands.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                HoldemHand hand1 = hands[j];
                //Parallel.For(j + 1, hands.Count, k =>
                for (int k = j + 1; k < hands.Count; k++)
                {
                    HoldemHand hand2 = hands[k];
                    if (!hand1.Contains(hand2))
                    {
                        FlopEquityHoldemHandPair holdemHandPair = new
                          FlopEquityHoldemHandPair(hand1, hand2);
                        if (!flopPairs.ContainsKey(holdemHandPair))
                        {
                            // next line triggers a loop of 1980 iterations
                            flopPairs.Add(holdemHandPair, new
                            FlopEquityHoldemHandPair(new
                            EquityHoldemHand(hand1), new
                            EquityHoldemHand(hand2), flop));
                        }
                    }
                }//);
            }//);


            // WRITE FILE FOR CURRENT FLOP
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (FlopEquityHoldemHandPair pair in flopPairs.Values)
            {
                // Null value appears in flopPairs.Values and the list of values is around 200 short of the 600k values it should have
                sb.AppendLine(pair.ToString());
            }
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());

            // reports calculation progress 1% at a time
            int num = ((int)(i * 100 / 22100));
            if (num > progress)
            {
                progress = num;
                Console.WriteLine("Progress: " + progress + "%");
            }
        }
    }//);

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine("Finished in " + elapsedMs / 60000 + "mins");
    return true;
}
```

When I arrive at the `foreach` loop late in this code, some items in flopPairs. Values are null and the dictionary is not quite as big as it should be - as though some calculations did not finish before the code moved on. I apologize that this code is not runnable without more code but there is a lot to provide. I can attempt to provide a minimal simplified example that runs if the problem is not fairly obvious to somebody.

Comment: According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153729/does-parallel-foreach-block) paralell foreach should block until the last part of the loop has finished. | Please specify with a comment on what line you get the Null value.

Comment: Its a Parallel For rather than Parallel Foreach. Not sure if that makes a difference. I've added a comment in the code where the null value occurs

Comment: I have two advices for you. One is to avoid nested `Parallel` loops. One `Parallel` loop is enough for most workloads. Nesting one inside the other just adds overhead. The other advice is to study threading systematically before attempting to write multithreading programs. You must familiarize yourself with the concepts of thread-synchronization, race conditions, memory barriers etc. There is a lot to learn, and it's unlikely that you'll be successful just by intuition and sheer lack. Here is a valuable online resource: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm not nesting Parallel loops. I've tried each of the ones commented out in the code but each was tried individually to see if the positioning cured the problem or affected performance.

Comment: Ah, OK. My guess is that your problems are caused by multiple threads accessing and modifying shared state concurrently and without synchronization. To fix these problems ideally you should make sure that each iteration of the loop can work with an isolated island of data. If all loops have to work with a common set of data, then you'll have to add a lot of synchronization (blocks of code with exclusive access by one thread at a time), which will kill most of the benefits of parallelism.

Comment: `Dictionary` is not thread-safe, so funky data is not surprising. Consider using a thread-safe collection as as [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @JohnWu thanks - that seems to have solved my problem. Had no idea the Dictionary was causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Wu stated in the comments, Dictionary is not thread safe and was causing my problems. Using ConcurrentDictionary was the correct answer